# Android Studio Gradle Build Failed Error: Program type already present

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I am Getting this Error after Build in Android Studio

Error: Program type already present: com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip$1

This is the Dependency i have added to my app build.gradle
`implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1@aar'`

please help me to solve this problem thanks in advance

Comment: First try with invalidate cache and restart check if it is working or not . Else follow this link you will come to know what u need. https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/issues/315

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried invalidate cache and restart still same prob exists:( Can anyone explain exclude module: is this can help to solve this problem like this`implementation ('com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'){
                exclude module: 'here what need to put'
            }`

Comment: add this to the line to dependencies 
{ implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1' } instead of {com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1@aar}

Answer (score 0):

in Android studio go to file-> then click ->project Structure then click Dependencies->then delete the implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1@aar' then click Apply then ok. gradel build successfully.

Comment: try to set color in xml page,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, the problem is solved since am using the same dependency two times the actual dependancy is `implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.1'`